# CSS border property breaks inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two DIVs side by side, 50% both with a border. I created one Div Container and two inside them, it works until I put the `border` property.

When Border exists, the DIVs are rendered in two lines:

```css
body {
    background-color:cadetblue;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
}

#divL, #divR {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="divL">L</div><div id="divR">R</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But when I remove the border rule, it works as expected.

```css
body {
    background-color:cadetblue;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
}

#divL, #divR {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="divL">L</div><div id="divR">R</div>
    </div>
```

How can I put a border to `divL` and `divR` ?

Comment: @Nenad Vracar's answer is correct. However, I would add `box-sizing` to all elements, rather than just this instance. `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` The reason that you need `box-sizing` in the first place is b/c the browsers are not calculating the widths of `padding, margin, and border` when using widths of other elements. See here: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)  so border width will be included in div's `50%` width.

```css
body {
  background-color:cadetblue;
}

#container {
  width: 800px;
}

#divL, #divR {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="divL">L</div><div id="divR">R</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nenad! I wasn't aware of the regular behavior or border.

Comment: You're welcome. Note: this also applies to padding of element.

Answer (score 1):

you using the width 50% and also using 2px width of border

```css
body {
    background-color:cadetblue;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
}

#divL, #divR {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="divL">L</div><div id="divR">R</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In this way I have to be careful with the border width also don't? 2px will work, 6px don´t.

Comment: Govind Bhai, This is not the correct answer, if the requirement is 50% then why are you reducing width to 48%..

Answer (score 0):

Both are div's have 50% with and you give extra border. so that

```
50% + 50% + 2px (border) = 100% ( container ) + 2px ( extra )
```

but we have 100% size of container, so need to adjust both div's with in 100 percent.

You can give 49% width to both div's.

```
#divL, #divR {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

I Hope It will also work.

Comment: What if 1px does _not_ equal 1%?

Comment: then you need to decrease Div's width to adjust that 1px border width, and use media css if getting screen size related issue.